# Query multiple relationships in model october cms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, illuminate-container

Hi I'm trying to make an combined query with October CMS active record implementation to filter out user selected input.

The are four models a `Color, Series, Department` and `Product` with the relationships as follows:

The `Product` model

```
public $belongsTo = [
  'color' => 'depcore\parts\Models\Color',
];


public $belongsToMany = [
  'series' => [
    'depcore\parts\Models\Series',
    'table' => 'depcore_parts_products_series',
    'order' => 'name',
    ],
  'departments' => [
    'depcore\parts\Models\Department',
    'table' => 'depcore_parts_products_departments',
    // 'order' => 'name'
    ]
];
```

`Department` and `Series` model

```
public $hasMany = [
  'products' => [
    '\depcore\parts\Models\Product',
    'table' => 'depcore_parts_products_departments',
  ]
];
```

And `Color` model

```
public $hasMany = [
  'products' => [
    '\depcore\Parts\Models\Product'
  ]
];
```

The user input is sent via ajax to the function which looks like this right now

```
public function onFilterProducts(){

  $filters = Request::input('Filter');

  if ( isset( $filters['colors'] ) or isset( $filters['departments'] ) or isset ( $filters['series'] ) ) {

    // $this->page['products'] = Product::whereIn ( 'color_id', $filters['colors']   )->take( 10 )->get();
    $this->page['products'] = Product::where ( function ( $query ) use  ( $filters ) {

      if ( isset ( $filters['colors'] ) ) $query->whereIn('color_id', $filters['colors']);
      if ( isset ( $filters['series'] ) ) $query->with(
        ['series'=> function ( $subquery ) {
          $subquery->whereIn('series_id', $filters['series']);
      }]);

    }  )->take(9)->get();

  }
  else
    $this->page['products'] =  Product::listFrontEnd();

}
```

As you can see I'm trying to make a filter on the many-to-many relation with the series model after the color query (this one works OK).

The problem is with the many-to-many relation I've tried to use different approaches to this problem with either no error ( but also no result ) or with an error saying that the below function `where` does not work.

```
if ( isset ( $filters['series'] ) ) $query->series()->whereIn ( 'series', $filters['series'] );
```

> "Call to undefined method depcore\parts\Models\Product::where()" on
>   line 1421 of
>   /var/www/public/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php

I don't know if this is possible to achieve this way or do I need to make a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution that I've come up with, making another anonymous function using then the `whereIn` method

```
if ( isset ( $filters['series'] ) ) {
   $query->whereHas ( 'series', function ( $q ) use  ( $filters ){ 
        $q->whereIn ( 'id', $filters['series'] ); } 
 );
  }
```